# Xcode Command CodeSign failed with a nonzero exit code when running Juce's projucer

Tags: xcode, xcode15, juce

Hello I have this error inside Xcode where the build always fails whenever I try to run Projucer from Juce.

[image]

I have searched the internet for a solution to this issue, and none of them worked for me.

Comment: You should go to the report navigator, find your failed build and look at the output of what exactly went wrong.